# NGINX different configurations for sub domains

Tags: nginx

I have the subdomain panel.example.com pointed to Pterodactyl Panel using their pterodactyl.conf, however, I want to have a different config so example.com resolves to my WHMCS. I tried creating just the server but it would always return 403 unauthorized.

Comment: Can you please share your nginx config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue and it is no longer present